# How to copy all files found with script to another folder using Windows Shell

Tags: shell, cmd

I want to copy the files that are found from a search into a folder.

The script 
`where /r C:\ *.jpg *.jpeg *.png *.gif >> C:\output.txt`

gives a text document with the location of the files I want. How can I create a copy of the files found from the search into some output folder X:\output\

I want to get copies of all images in a folder including all subfolders into an output folder of all the images.

Comment: Are you sure your code works?? I mean, the file patterns are wrong (they should read `*.jpg` rather than `*jpg`, for instance). Furthermore, `where` would also return a file like `*.jpg.exe` (given that system variable `PATHEXT` has got its default value), just to mention it. What about using `dir /B /S /A:-D *.jpg *.jpeg *.png *.gif`? To capture the result, take a look at [`for /F`](https://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html); to copy files, well, check out [`copy`](https://ss64.com/nt/copy.html)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could get the output of a command with a `for /f` loop:

```
for /f "delims=" %%A in ('where /r C:\ *.jpg *.jpeg') do echo working on %%A
```

or process a file with:

```
for /f "delims=" %%A in (C:\output.txt) do echo working on %%A
```

But `for` is capable to do it itself:

```
for /r "C:\" %%A in (*.jpg *.jpeg *.png *.gif) do ECHO copy "%%~fA" "X:\output\%%~nxA"
```

(remove the `ECHO` after troubleshooting to actually enable the copy command)

Note:
- this doesn't take care of possible duplicate names.
- this is batch file syntax. For use on command line, replace every `%%` with a single `%`